# How does one clean these filters after 6 months?

Tags: air-quality, air-filter

There's a [great project on This Old House](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aw7fUMhNov8) that uses 4x MERV 13 filters to purify the air on your house (*even against covid-19 they say*)

**Question;** When it has been running in your house for 6 months, how do you clean it out safely?

Comment: It's kind of Half Bakery without knowing how to do this.

Comment: Most furnace filters are not meant to be cleaned, just replaced.

Comment: I discard those standard filters about every 2 months.

Comment: Half Bakery and half ? Deli?

Comment: @AlaskaMan https://www.halfbakery.com/

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You just remove the fan and build a new 4 filter base. You could remove the bottom and vacuum all the filters to remove some of the dirt but but just replacing would be better. Don't count on this stopping COVID-19.

Answer (score 0):

Regular media filters of any amount will not stop "covid" or any other virus. I was told many years age that an electronic air cleaner will stop or kill viruses. Is this a true statement, I really don't know but I do know that they stop almost everything even cigarette smoke. Will the above mentioned 4 X Merv 13 filters stop Covid? probably not but they did get your attention and some people may even believe that they will. They say that UV light will kill the virus and now every store sells them. Do they work???